# Android TV: Remove shadow from Item in ListRowPresenter

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am trying to remove shadow from the list item when that Horizontal list is not in focus. I am extending my fragment from `RowSupportFragment` and then creating `ListRowPresenter` like this

```
val listRowPresenter = ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_XSMALL)
    listRowPresenter.shadowEnabled = false
    ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(listRowPresenter)
```

and adding two `ArrayObjectAdapter` later on when data comes from server.

```
    listRowAdapter?.add(ListRow(null, objectAdapter1))
    listRowAdapter?.add(ListRow(null, objectAdapter2))
```

The line `listRowPresenter.shadowEnabled = false` is suppose to remove the shadow from the list rows but it is not giving the required behavior. Can anyone point to some classes or any example that can be helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this i am posting it for future reference. If you want to remove the shadow from the items of unselected row you need to add these to you `ListRowPresenter`.

```
    listRowPresenter.shadowEnabled = false
    listRowPresenter.selectEffectEnabled = false
```

and it will remove the shadow from the item. For more customization you can override `ShadowOverlayHelper` class that is initialized inside `ListRowPresenter`.